# ADMM diverges on L1 regression

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multipliers

TLDR: Why does ADMM diverge when solving $\ell_1$ regression?

### Introduction

I am learning about convex optimisation and wanted to solve a simple exercise that I am having issues with. I want to solve a $\ell_1$ regression using ADMM (Alternating Direction Method of Multiplies, [https://stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/admm.html)). Not because I have to, but because I want to try it and have a little fun.

### Problem set up

The problem is:

$$\min_\beta \|X\beta -y \|_1$$

where $X$ has dimensions $N \times D$, $\beta$ is a $D$-dimensional vector and $y$ has length $N$.

What I wanted to try is using an augmented variable $\alpha$ to make the problem linear. That is, I want to solve

$$\min_{\alpha, \beta} \alpha^\top 1_N \quad \text{s.t.} \quad X\beta-y \leq \alpha \quad \text{and} \quad -X\beta + y \leq \alpha $$

these constraints are quivalent to $|X\beta-y| \leq \alpha$.

I now write down the Augmented Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}=\alpha^\top 1_N + \lambda_1 (\alpha-X\beta+y) + \lambda_2 (\alpha+X\beta-y) + \rho_1/2 \|\alpha-X\beta+y\|_2^2 + \rho_2/2 \|\alpha+X\beta-y\|_2^2$$

with $\lambda_1 \leq 0$ and $\lambda_2 \leq 0$ (Constraint should be positive, so during minimisation the $\lambda$s should be negative. See Bishop, Pattern Recognition Appendix).

I initialise:
$$\rho_1 \leftarrow 1$$
$$\rho_2 \leftarrow 1$$
$$\lambda_1 \leftarrow 1_N$$
$$\lambda_2 \leftarrow 1_N$$
$$\alpha \leftarrow |X\beta-y|$$

Now I update in the following order:

We solve $\nabla_\beta \mathcal{L}=0$ and use the pseudo inverse (same as OLS estimator) to get

$$\beta \leftarrow \frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2 + \rho_1 - \rho_2} (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top \left[\lambda_1 (\alpha + y) + \lambda_2 (\alpha - y) + \rho_1 (\alpha + y) + \rho_2 (\alpha - y) \right]$$

We solve $\nabla_\alpha \mathcal{L}=0$

$$\alpha \leftarrow - \frac{1}{\rho_1 + \rho_2} \left[1_N + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 +(\rho_2-\rho_1) (X \beta - y) \right]$$

Next the dual ascent on $\lambda_1$:

$$\lambda_1 \leftarrow \max \{\lambda_1 + \rho_1 (\alpha-X\beta+y), 0\}$$

and $\lambda_2$:

$$\lambda_2 \leftarrow \max \{ \lambda_2 + \rho_2 (\alpha+X\beta-y), 0 \}$$

### The Issue

$\alpha$ grows to $-\infty$ quite quickly and the loss goes to $\infty$. I can't seem to make it stop. What am I doing wrong? I tried playing with hyperparameters.

Edit: [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dXOHCGGTZ9dlhuwBMp9rbJZ6BTat7ObN?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADMM assumes that the constraints being added as penalties are equality constraints. In your reformulation of the l1 objective into inequality constraints i.e., $X\beta - y \leq \alpha$ and $-X \beta + y \leq \alpha $, you first have to convert those inequality constraints into equality constraints using slack variables and then dualize those equalities.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented @batwing's suggestion and it works. Let $\phi_1 \geq 0$, $\phi_2 \geq 0$ be slack variables (which we initialise to $0_N$), the Lagrangian becomes:

$$\mathcal{L}=\alpha^\top 1_N + \lambda_1^\top (\alpha-X\beta+y-\phi_1) + \lambda_2^\top(\alpha+X\beta-y-\phi_2) + \rho_1/2 \|\alpha-X\beta+y-\phi_1\|_2^2 + \rho_2/2 \|\alpha+X\beta-y-\phi_2\|_2^2$$
with $\phi_1 \geq 0$ and $\phi_2 \geq 0$.

The update for $\beta$ becomes:

$$\beta \leftarrow - \frac{1}{\rho_1 + \rho_2} (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top \left[ (\lambda_2 - \lambda_2) - \rho_1(\alpha + y - \phi_1) + \rho_2 (\alpha-y-\phi_2) \right]$$

The update for $\alpha$ becomes:

$$\alpha \leftarrow - \frac{1}{\rho_1 + \rho_2} \left[1_N + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 +(\rho_2-\rho_1) (X \beta - y) - \rho_1 \phi_1 - \rho_2 \phi_2 \right]$$

Solve for $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$:

$$\phi_1 \leftarrow \max\left(0, \frac{1}{\rho_1}\lambda_1 + \alpha - X\beta + y \right)$$
$$\phi_2 \leftarrow \max\left(0, \frac{1}{\rho_1}\lambda_1 + \alpha + X\beta - y \right)$$

And then we perform dual ascent on dual and slack variables:

$$\lambda_1 \leftarrow \lambda_1 + \rho_1 (\alpha-X\beta+y-\phi_1)$$
$$\lambda_2 \leftarrow \lambda_2 + \rho_2 (\alpha+X\beta-y-\phi_2)$$

And now it works :)

Comment: One comment, since slack variables are primal variables, I believe the standard way of ADMM update should be to perform slack variable minimization before dual ascent. Also, note that by introducing slack variables $\phi$, you should also introduce the constraint $\phi \geq 0$. I did not see that manifest in your formulation.

Comment: @batwing thanks for your comment. I was under the impresison that squaring $\phi$ means I do not have to constrain it.

Comment: Squaring $\phi$ makes the equality constraint non-convex. TBH, I am not aware whether ADMM coverges to the optimal solution for equality constrained quadratic constraints.

Comment: Thanks. So if I dont square $\phi$, do I just clamp it to $\phi \geq 0$ after each gradient descent update?

Comment: You have a couple of options:
1. You can solve the QP w.r.t $\phi$ variables using a simple minimization algorithm like coordinate descent or use an off the shelf solver.
2. I suspect there is a way to obtain a closed form solution to your problem. If you are able to write down the optimization problem w.r.t $\phi_1$ (resp. $\phi_2$) as min $\| \phi_1 -v_1\|_2^2 + \text{ terms independent of $\phi_1$}$ s.t. $\phi_1 \geq 0$, then the minimizer is obtained by just clamping $v_1$ as you suggested. However, you need to first figure out a way to rearrange the objective in the form I described.

Comment: thanks. for the explanation. I updated my answer once again. Hopefully, now it is correct. It does work :)

Comment: I regret not mentioning this earlier, in your update you seem to update $\beta$ based on previous iteration's $\alpha$. Then you update $\alpha$ based on current estimate for $\beta$. Finally you simultaneously estimate for $\phi_1, \phi_2$ based on current estimates for $\alpha, \beta$. In summary, you are making 3 sequential updates for the primal variables. To the best of my knowledge, ADMM is guaranteed to return the optimal solution with only 2 sets of updates. My suggestion is, solve for $\alpha, \beta$ simultaneously, and then for $\phi_1, \phi_2$ simultaneously as you currently have.

Comment: Thanks you for that note. I will read up on this. Do you mean the update for $\alpha_t$ should be based on $\beta_{t-1}$ and the update for $\beta_t$ is based on $\alpha_{t-1}$ instead of updating $\alpha_t$ based on $\beta_t$ as I do above?

Comment: I was suggesting that $\alpha^{(t)}, \beta^{(t)}$ depend on $\phi_1^{(t-1)}, \phi_2^{(t-1)}$, while $\phi_1^{(t)}, \phi_2^{(t)}$ depends on $\alpha^{(t)}, \beta^{(t)}$ .